# How can I print all the submenu of main menu in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to print the submenu text of mainmenu of first list[Electronics] of
in selenium webdriver.
url : https://www.flipkart.com
But there is some issue to take the xpath of that sumMenu.
How can I take the xpath and all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following `x-path` to get all sub menus of main menu "Electronics"

```
//span[.='Electronics']/following-sibling::ul//li/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code. Change value the `String searchSubMenu = "Electronics";`   if you want get text other sub menu, hope this helps.

```
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

    //wait login popup and click
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();

    String searchSubMenu = "Electronics";

    int totalSubMenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'Wbt_B2')]")).size();

    System.out.println("Search for : " +searchSubMenu);

    for(int i=1; i<=totalSubMenu; i++) {
        String getTextSubMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(@class,'Wbt_B2')])[" +i +"]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Get Sub Menu Title : "+ getTextSubMenu);
        if (getTextSubMenu.equals(searchSubMenu)) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(@class,'Wbt_B2')])[" +i +"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String targetAllGetText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[contains(@class,'_3GtRpC')])[" +i +"]")).getText();
            System.out.println(targetAllGetText);
            break;
        }
    }

    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you : Please try 
String SubMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of element")).getText();
            System.out.println(SubMenu);
if you want Size:
int Size =driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of element"));
 System.out.println(Size);